# Is it common for a university to remain unresponsive to queries?

Tags: application, united-kingdom, international-students

I'm planning to study in the u.k. I've never been to the u.k. but is it common there to remain unresponsive to the students' queries?
I've sent a few emails to the student service team for some queries. They replied me once or twice and on one of them, idk if they forwarded it by accident ot not, they sent me the conversation they had about me through emails including the answer to my query. They were complaining to each other how I email multiple ppl at the same time. I'm not sure if that's a professional way to deal with anyone even though I'm a student.
After that, I sent a few emails because I urgently need to work on my visa, and they haven't answered to any of them. It's been roughly 9days since I sent my unanswered query.
Could they be ignoring my emails on purpose?
I've been informed that an organisation is to take certain period of time to reply before when I was emailling other institutes, but never experienced this unresponsive instutue...

Comment: It doesn't sound very nice, but: What's your definition of "a few"? Why do you email "multiple people"?

Comment: Unprofessional at least. But it could be that you sent much mails and perhaps none was clear enough.

Comment: This can be frustrating and is unfortunately common behavior. The advice I'd recommend keeping in mind are (1) keep your emails as short as possible, while containing an easily identified, specific question; (2) try to make sure you are contacting the right people, for example I wouldn't expect most of their staff to know anything about visa issues. University bureaucracies are giant beasts and n one person is familiar with every part. In any case, do your best to avoid emails where you describe your situation at length and where it's not clear what you're asking from them. Good luck.

Comment: Your question here on Academia.SE is a good example: you ask "Is it common for a university to remain unresponsive to queries?" when you actually need to know "How can I get student support staff to answer my queries?" Try to be direct, simple, and polite. One again, very best of luck.

Comment: You need to contact the international office of the uni for visa questions. Student services are for helping existing students with problems like replacement library cards, IT issues or timetabling clashes.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, it is very common for universities in the UK to be unresponsive, and for administrators to be unkind and feel entitled.

Comment: Can you clarify what stage you are at in the application process and whether you are applying for undergrad, master or PhD. Have you already filled in the official application form? Do you have a official offer? If so, is it from the university, from a department, or from an individual supervisor?

Answer (score -1):

They complained that you've *emailed multiple people*; maybe that breaks some organisational hierarchy and given they are British, they might be too serious about the hierarchy thing.

You should probably send one more short email to **exactly one** specific, most relevant recipient, apologize for any *mistake in correspondence on your part* and politely share your query again while mentioning the urgency.

Comment: Do people really percieve the British as serious about organisational hierarchy? In the army I imagine that holds, but not in academia...

Comment: @astronat, the observation was not meant to be disrespectful, rather, to indicate the sense of order and discipline that the world generally assigns to the British.